# firebug script panel not showing any scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I am trying to debug my javascript & jQuery and step through it using firebug.
I am running my code on an Apache server (2.4) on a windows machine. 
I used the firefox browser version 18.

When i go to run my code, I can't see my javascript (external file) in the scripts panel.
I see the linked jQuery library on the panel but I dont see my javascript code.

On the Firebug, the scripts are clearly linked in the HTML panel. But on the script panel, only the jQuery.js is visible. i would post a screen shot but i dont have enough reputation right now.

I dont know what is going on and what i have to do in order to be able to step through my javascript code.

**UPDATE**

I placed the "debugger" on my javascript code but it still not showing on the 'script panel'.

```
debugger;
$(document).ready(function () {
var email_default = "Enter your email address...";
$(':input[type="email"]').val(email_default).on('focus', function () {
if ($(this).val() == email_default) {
    $(this).val(' ');
}
});
```

I also tried to do a browser refresh, disable and re-enable all the firebug panels- but it still won't show my external javascript. I had also double checked my file location & directories to make sure i am linking it correctly.

Comment: put 'debugger' at start of your code. and keep firebug opened. it will automatically stop at debugger.

Comment: Ok i think i got it working.  After adding the 'debugger' command thing, I like refreshed the browser a bunch of times and then restarted firebug. It seemed to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If Firebug (or other browser developer tools) doesn't show a JavaScript in the list of available scripts, this means it has a syntax error.

In that case you need to switch to the *Console* panel and check there for the error.

*Notes:*

As [mentioned in a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31645823/432681), there can also be other reasons why there are no scripts shown in the list:

Since Firefox 49.0 and Firebug 2.0.18 the *Script* panel is completely broken. This is due to some internal Firefox API changes. And because [Firebug is officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/), this unfortunately won't get fixed anymore.

There was also a bug in Firebug 2.0.11 (and below) in combination with Firefox 39.0 causing this problem. This bug got filed as [issue 7918](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7918) and fixed for version 2.0.12.
It happens when the *Script* panel is enabled and you close Firebug and then reopen it.