# Alert does not trigger, JS is not detected

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I think I might be going crazy at this point.  I had an ASP page working yesterday, and came in today to Firebug telling me it cannot detect the JavaScript on the page.  Love it when things change after not touching them.

So I start trying to figure out what is happening.  **I tried** *slimming down the code*, *[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120063/1618257)*, *restarting Firefox*, *saving the page under a new name* and loading the new one, and *adding a ridiculous amount of code I generally consider unnecessary*.  I even tried *removing everything from the page and changing it* to this:

```
<script>
alert("yay");
</script>
```

Does not trigger alert, and Firebug says "No JavaScript on this page".  I've been looking for explanations for almost 2 hours and cannot figure out what is happening.  *I know I did not deactivate anything because other pages will show JavaScript and function properly*.  I also know that no add-ons are causing it.

[image: HTML]

[image: JS]

I am using Firefox 28.0 (also tried on 27.0.1).  *Opening the page in Chrome triggers the alert.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the tab and opening the same link in a new tab seemed to resolve the issue.

I'm not sure if any of the prior attempts factored in, so I will list them as well.  To be clear, *none of these worked*, but may have paved the way in some fashion.

- Restarting Firefox
- "Clear Activation List" on Firebug
- Save page under new filename and load the new page
- Uninstalling add-ons (all of them)
- Create new profile and load page on that profile
- Add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top
- Add `type="text/javascript"` to script tags
- Add `charset="utf-8"` to script tags
- Add `<meta charset="utf-8">` in `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

(Damn I meant to post this as a comment).

As you responded I'll re-popualate...

I create jsfiddle,

```
<body>
<script>
    alert("yay");
</script>
</body>
```

Also ensure your browser has javascript enabled.

Comment: Yes.  Your fiddle works for me as well.  The thing that confuses me is why the same code would work in one place and not the other.

Comment: Hmm, and does firebug pick up that javascript ok?  I imagine it does.  Could you try another browser (seems like a basic suggestion sorry) -then we can rule out the browser and work on the code.

Comment: It worked in Chrome, so I am suspecting the browser over the code.  After all, the code is **very** basic at this point.

Comment: Which version of mozilla is it?  Double check your javascript settings by going to:  about:config, search for "java" check that  javascript.enabled is not set to its default value of true, double-click it to switch it back to true.  If that is true, start firefox in safe mode to ensure none of the addons are causing it

Comment: Firefox 28.0, javascript.eneabled is true, no add-ons are causing it.

Comment: Quite strange, not sure I can help much more.  Have a read of this if you haven't already, I hope someone else has more suggestions: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/mXqMM__js8A

Comment: If JavaScript isn't enabled, the *Script* panel shows a message saying "Javascript is not enabled" and provides a hint how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions on the [Firebug's first aid page](https://getfirebug.com/firstaid).

I assume it's either some Firebug setting or a conflict with another extension. (I see at least YSlow and FlashFirebug installed.)

To check that you can [create a new profile and just install Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Firebug_into_a_clean_profile).

Comment: Making a new profile works, but it is not because of add-on conflicts?  I went back to default profile, uninstalled every add-on aside from Firebug, and it still does not work.  Even after uninstalling firebug, the JS for the page still does not function on default profile.