# Why does Firebug just display JavaScript after restarting Firefox?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

Even after i explicitly said that there is a difference in my bug from existing bug some modearators have marked it as duplicate may be i have not explicitly mentioned the difference so i am highlighting here

**In my case the error goes away ie., i am able to view the javascipt in the debugger once I restart the Firefox**

I know there is a [post, which mentions the issue of Firebug not displaying JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17086478/432681) with the following error message:

> If  tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).

But in my case the error goes away once I restart the Firefox.

This has been happening since the last update of Firefox. Earlier versions were not having this problem.

Is there any way to tweek Firefox, so that I don't have to restart Firefox every time to debug my JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the browser does not interpret scripts with `type="text/x-jsrender"` and therefore Firebug (or the built-in DevTools debugger) doesn't display the contents of the `<script>` tag.

Also note that JsRender templates **are not** JavaScript, so they cannot be debugged with JavaScript debuggers. It is JsRender that uses the type `text/x-jsrender` as indicator that it needs to parse the contents within the `<script>` tag.

You will be able to see the contents of the tags within Firebug's *HTML* panel, though.

Comment: I dont want to debug jsrender i am mentioning jsrender because i  am using it in my app and i think current version of firefox is super sensitive to that . I want to debug my plain javascript and i dont have jsrender in my current page  iam developing such pages were getting debugged fine before the last update of firefox

Comment: after the last update some times the debugger does not display the javascript but displays it after restart

Comment: Ok, if your problem is not related to JsRender, you should clarify that in your question. So when it's about plain JavaScript, this seems to be a bug, which is filed as [issue #7918](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7918).

Comment: Something looks to be fixed in Firefox 40. So you may want to either use Firefox 38 ESR or Firefox 40 (currently beta).

See https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7918

Comment: In Firefox 40 the bug does not appear, though in Firefox 41 it's back again - at least when you just reload the page.