# Firebug has stopped showing me javascript source

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I've been developing a web application and testing as I go in Firefox, using the Firebug debugger when needed.  This morning I notice that my app is hanging somewhere, but The Firebug "Script" panel no longer shows me the content of any of the javascript files that it knows about. (it lists them all but choosing any of them does not show any source).  Also, it is set to break on exceptions and it is enabled, but exceptions do not trigger a break.

This is with Firefox 38.1.0.  It was installed yesterday, so I would suspect a bug in the new version, except that it did work yesterday.

Is there some sort of memory limitation?  My app did grow more complex yesterday with the addition of some new library code to it.

Has anyone experienced this and what is the workaround.

Comment: Seems like its a js error somewhere? Some loop of some kind that is using up all your cpu?

Comment: On the page that this is a duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086478/firebug-says-no-javascript-on-this-page-even-though-javascript-does-exist-on), the specific suggestion that helped was resetting Firefox, although I wonder if the same thing might not have been accomplished by simply removing the Firebug add-on and reinstalling it.