# Firebug is not working with Firefox version 50.0

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

I am using Firefox 50.0. After auto update of Firefox to version 50.0, Firebug has stopped working and attempting to use it is showing an inbuilt Firefox console while inspecting any DOM element.

Is there any patch to use Firebug on Firefox 50.0 version?

Comment: What do you need Firebug for, out of curiosity?

Comment: I need it for editing cookies, and checking ajax requests. I am more familiar with firebug. That's why I was looking for the solution.

Comment: On my Firefox 50, Firebug still works for the most functions. However, javascript is not detected anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40703920/4712173 for additional info. For now I'm running the last 49 version, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40631072/4712173 .
I really hope Firebug will be fixed since it is much better than any other dev tool I've tried and still trying ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why got Firebug removed after updating Firefox to version 50?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744448/why-got-firebug-removed-after-updating-firefox-to-version-50)

Comment: @Ryan - I NEED firebug. I'm long time web developer, did countless projects for over 12 years, doing highly complex projects and I'm telling you, I NEED firebug. I have endless contempt for anything other than Firebug, due to the fact the firebug is insanely easy to use. Must easier to edit styles, and you can run JS code and view the output in a MUCH better way than anything else imaginable. and more and more. the UX of firebug is sublime. I cannot update my Firefox for all eternity now :(

Comment: @vsync: Not updating Firefox is a terrible idea that will expose you to exploits. Just give the new developer tools a try; they’re the successor to Firebug.

Comment: @Ryan I use Firebug about 70% of the time for running JS code on websites or just to test small code. It has code highlight, history, pretty-print you can run a large amount of code and see the result side-by-side. Also when you inspect element with Firebug, you have the right-panel with "style, computed, layout, DOM, Events" which is **highly** useful. Especially the `DOM` panel per element. it's just perfect

Comment: @vsync: You know the built-in Firefox console has all of those too right?

Comment: @Ryan - it has *Scratchpad* which is a very poor imitation... I've asked this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41118844/104380)

Comment: @vsync: Why is it a “poor imitation”? And is that the only problem you have, then? You listed a whole bunch of other stuff that already exists before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146754/discussion-between-vsync-and-ryan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebug is not working on Mozilla version 52](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834636/firebug-is-not-working-on-mozilla-version-52)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Solve The problem by Changing Mozilla Browser Configuration Settings.

1. Open A Blank Tab
2. type about:config in address bar then press enter (click on  I accept the risk!)
3. find browser.tabs.remote.autostart
4. select the option then click the mouse right side
5. Turn The Option As False
6. Close the browser for restart browser
7. open browser again, inspect the element. I hope It Works Properly.

Answer (score 5):

I manage to get Firebug work again, so here is what I done.

Everyone knows that Firebug isn't being developed or maintained any longer because it can't work with e10s, so here is my workaround:

- Download **Firefox Developer edition** so you can allow XPI installation.
  *[firefox-53.0a2.en-US.win64.installer.exe](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-aurora/firefox-53.0a2.en-US.win64.installer.exe)* or 
  *[firefox-53.0a2.en-US.win32.installer.exe](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-aurora/firefox-53.0a2.en-US.win32.installer.exe)*
- Run Firefox developer edition after installing and go to the ***about:config*** (type in url bar)
  Find ***xpinstall.signatures.required*** (**set to false**) 
  Find ***browser.tabs.remote.autostart*** 
  (**set all to false:** *browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1* and *browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2*)

**NOTE:** The Multi-process architecture improves the browser's stability, performance and security by separating tasks into processes, you disabling it at own responsibility.

**After that you need to restart the browser.**

- Now you can go at the Firebug repository and install desired version
  [Here you can find all Firebug installations](https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/2.0/)

I chose latest firebug-2.0b8.xpi and it forking fine.

P.S. You can disable updates for Firefox Developer edition.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry because it doesn't work for you, cheek if you are followed all steps: Here's mine screenshot, it does fork fine, I use firebug daily. 
https://i.imgsafe.org/afb6a0bd66.png

Comment: link produces a 403 Forbidden    Code: AccessDenied. If you are still interested in running a XUL/preQuantum/<v57 Firefox, there are 99versions of firebug available through 'Classic Add-ons Archive' addon. https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/releases

Answer (score 4):

Head over to [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) website, you can see following message:

> The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer. We invite you to use the Firefox built-in DevTools instead.

Also [Sebastianz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/Sebastianz) told me,

> Firebug is discontinued. The team has split up, the former team leader Jan "Honza" Odvarko is working on the Firefox DevTools now.

As @Makyen said in his answer, **Firebug does not work with multiprocess Firefox**, so remove `Firebug` right now and try `Firefox DevTools` instead, it's not optional (*sadly*), unless you don't update Firefox :)

**Update 1**

Take a look @ [Why got Firebug removed after updating Firefox to version 50?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744448/why-got-firebug-removed-after-updating-firefox-to-version-50/40748127#40748127)

**Update 2**

Take a look @ my answer here: [how to revert firebug to old version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899502/how-to-revert-firebug-to-old-version/40957545#40957545)

Comment: But, Is there any patch to use Firebug on Firefox 50.0 version? As build in tool do not have even 25% functionality of it.. !  so the need to move to chrome.. Dev tool.. :(!!

Comment: @BJPatel Seems like `e10s` still is disabled by default in `v50`, but if for you is enable, You will be able to disable e10s for a while to keep using Firebug 2, but this won’t last forever. (`Firefox Dev tools` have some great features & have NOT some Firefbug's nice features, __but__ please don't leave Firefox & help to make that better than ever (by reporting bugs, ...))

Answer (score 3):

### Firebug does not work with multiprocess Firefox

The [Firebug site](http://getfirebug.com/) claims that:

> **Firebug 2.0.18** is compatible with Firefox 30 – 52

However, it also explains that [emphasis mine]:

> **Firebug 2.0.18** fixes issue 8030. The extension is marked as multi-process (e10s) compatible so, it isn’t blacklisted and users can continue installing it. This way Firebug can help users to easily migrate into built-in Firefox developer tools – in case it’s running in multi-process enabled browser. **When opened in a multi-process Firefox, Firebug’s tools cannot be used.** Firebug will then only assist the user with migration to Firefox’s built-in tools.

They also direct you to read: [Unifying Firebug & Firefox DevTools](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/)

That page says that [emphasis mine]:

> **Firebug 2 doesn’t work in multi-process browsers (i.e. e10s) and converting it is too complex, so it will stop working when e10s is activated in Firefox.** You will be able to disable e10s for a while to keep using Firebug 2, but this won’t last forever.

The fact that Firebug does not actually work in multiprocess Firefox will account for different people having different experiences with Firebug working or not working in a particular version of Firefox.  Firefox automatically enabling multiprocess mode will depend on multiple factors, including what other add-ons are installed in the profile.

### Using Firebug in newer versions of Firefox

Thus, to use Firebug in newer versions of Firefox, you will need to [disable Firefox from entering multiprocess mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1062853). This can be done from the `about:preferences` page (also available from Tools➞Options). This an option which is under the "General" tab as "Enable multi-process Firefox ...". If multiprocess is not available, this option will not be shown. This option can also be changed by adjusting the preference `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` from `about:config`. [Note: `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` and `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1` also appear to be used to indicate default states, thus I suggest using the `about:preferences` page to change this option.]

You can determine if your Firefox is currently running in multiprocess mode by looking in `about:support`.  The line "Multiprocess Windows" under "Application Basics" will state if multiprocess is enabled or disabled.

### Set up profiles explicitly for testing

Personally, I have different profiles set up for each of multiprocess explicitly disabled and [multiprocess explicitly enabled](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Force_Enable) (set `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` to `true`), so I can perform testing under both conditions, with the state of multiprocess being enabled/disabled being known in advance.

Comment: @Hikari, In the more than a year since this became an issue, Firefox has changed. It's not surprising that an unmaintained add-on which deeply changes Firefox no longer works with newer versions. If you *really* want to use Firebug, install an old version of Firefox and use Firebug with that version. Multiple versions of Firefox installed on the same computer at the same time is quite easy. You just have to select a different install directory and add ` -no-remote -ProfileManager` to the command line which is used to execute Firefox (for Windows, this is in the "target" of the shortcut).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I updated Firefox. I was so addicted to firebug but I moved on to Firefox developer edition - https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

It also comes with the firebug theme which resembles firebug UI and its efficient.Just install FDE and activate the firebug theme as shown in the image below : [image]

Comment: How can we validate any written xpath here? I cannot see any such option

Comment: There was a bug that was reported and fixed that caused that issue. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857614/how-to-find-xpath-of-an-element-in-firefox-inspector

Answer (score 2):

I had the same unexpected surprise when ubuntu updated FFX and suddenly things like the script panel stopped working.  Since I was in the middle of working on something with a short deadline, I was not going to have the luxury of learning the firefox developer toolset and desperately needed to get firebug working.  The fix that finally worked for me was to set Firefox preferences not to update.  Then download v 49.0.2
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

I also had to tell Ubuntu not to include firefox in it's upgrades.

It looks like firebug will no longer be maintained as a seperate project, so you will want to get familiar w/ the built in dev tools, but hopefully this buys you some time.  Worth mentioning (if I'm reading this right, it sounds like it will be integrated into the native tools:

https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/

https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next

Answer (score 1):

Its working. You need to install one more add-on "Firepicker" and restart the Firefox.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepicker/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue by simply downgrading to mozilla old version using this url:

- open https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.0/win64/en-US/
- download and run the .exe setup
- Go to Settings - > Add Ons
- Click on extensions and search for firebug and firepath and then add those extensions

Hope this should resolve the issue. For those using Windows 32 machine can use the url 
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.0/win32/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/xpath-helper/

Open a new tab and navigate to any webpage. I have used www.DemoQA.com for demo.
Hit Ctrl-Shift-X (or Command-Shift-X on OS X), or click the XPath Helper button in the toolbar, to open the XPath Helper console.
Hold down Shift as you mouse over elements on the page. The query box will continuously update to show the XPath query for the element below the mouse pointer, and the results box will show the results for the current query.
If desired, edit the XPath query directly in the console. The results box will immediately reflect your changes.
Repeat step (2) to close the console.