# Firebug 2+ Add-on Doesn't Show Error Info

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

Please see attached image for reference. Until very recently, Firebug add-on in Firefox would show a red error count on top right and the Console would have the javascript error info.

But looks like Firebug is no longer supported and is being integrated inside Developer Tools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug and for that link you'd see that the error count only could be now displayed but only after pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> keys - and even then error info not displayed.

I would like to see the error count red as soon as the page loads. I'd also like to see error info in the 'errors' tab of the Console, as it used to be.  I have looked for a solution - even tried to revert to older Firebug but so far no success.

Any idea?

[image: Current Firefox/Firebug screen]

Comment: Note, what you are seeing is *not* Firebug but the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/) with a Firebug theme. This is because Firebug doesn't work together with [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) and the Firebug button automatically toggles the DevTools instead of Firebug in that case. Read more about that on the [related Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind,

Per this post: [How to revert Firebug to old version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899502/how-to-revert-firebug-to-old-version/40910225#40910225)

I set all instances of `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` to false and Firebug seems to be working as it was before.

This maybe temp solution but it fixes my problem :)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot obviously shows the [Firefox DevTools (with Firebug theme) and *not* the Firebug](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

To see the JavaScript errors in the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) you need to toggle the related filter. To do that click the [image: JavaScript errors filter button] button in the console toolbar.

Having said that, there's a [bug regarding the error count](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228034) causing the number shown in the [Developer Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI) to be wrong, i.e. it often doesn't match the number of errors logged to the console.

Comment: Thank you. But, no, that error showing was not working for me. Before I did the fix per my own Answer here, the behavior was: I load a page; if it was missing a file to download (I know it's not javascript but still), then no red count would show. Even if I were to press the JS button. I am happy with reverting back and I hope Firebug/Web Developer Tools team would really look into these issues.

Comment: As I've noted, there's a bug, which causes the number of errors displayed in the Developer Toolbar to be incorrect. I've updated my answer to make it a bit more obvious.

Comment: Thank you. So I just undid my reversion, clicked on the Firebug icon on top to bring up the web console in the bottom of the browser, clicked on the JS panel to enable that, loaded that page which used to show an error about the missing image and still nothing--nothing on the top right FBug icon and nothing inside the Web Console. I have (again) implemented per my own Answer. The FBug inside the Developer Tool is not good my needs.

Comment: You should add a screenshot of the error you see in the Firebug console to your question. A missing image rather sounds like a network error rather than a JavaScript error. To see different kinds of errors you need to enable the other filters, too. Note, the Firebug icon generally does *not* show the number of errors anymore once multi-process Firefox is enabled. And also note that Firebug definitely stops working starting from Firefox 57, because [then Firefox only supports WebExtensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/) (and Firebug isn't one).

Comment: Yes, it is a network error--a missing file. But the point is that old FireBug would immediately show such problems--whether network or javascript--on the Firebug icon on top right--even if FireBug was not launched. That immediately drew attention to some problem in the code. Similarly, while working on javascript code, any page reloads would show the errors on top right and inside the 'errors' panel a pretty detailed description of the error. With those two critical things gone I have to revert to the old FireBug.

Comment: Just tested it with again with a clean profile using Firefox 53.0.2 and Firebug 2.0.19 and the Firebug button doesn't show the error badge on anymore. Anyway, the Developer Toolbar is expected to show the error count (though currently has the aforementioned bug) and by default all filters to show errors are activated in the DevTools console. So, if you don't see the errors there even when all filters are activated, it's a bug and you should [report it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Console), so it can get fixed.

Comment: Thank you. FireBug is probably the #1 reason for developers to use FireFox. Indeed, against my corporate policy of only using IE (the horror!), I have been using FireFox because of FireBug. I hope the team realizes how serious this bug is.