# Multiline mode for Firefox debug tools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

**Note for close vote AIs:** I'm not asking for software recommendation on another product. That would be off topic anyway. I'm asking whether something is possible in .

One of the great features of Firebug - which is now discontinued and already started to malfunction - was the side to side script editor with console:

[image: image description]

I can't figure out how to enable this in the Firefox Developer tools. I looked in settings but there's nothing about it. Is that even possible in Firefox Developer tools? Or maybe it's simply not possible?

I do know that with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> you can enter multiple lines in the console, but when you press enter the line resets.

Comment: Related [Firefox Developer Tools JS editor (like firebug)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118844/firefox-developer-tools-js-editor-like-firebug)

Comment: Are you familiar with [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Scratchpad)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firefox DevTools have something similar called [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad), which is a separate panel allowing you to execute multi-line JavaScript code. Furthermore, the command line allows you to enter line breaks by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and automatically breaks into the next line when the entered expression is not finished, e.g. when you write `document.` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As those features are not exactly what Firebug provided and the UI is somewhat requiring getting used to, there is a [request to implement a multi-line mode for the console](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1133849) like in Firebug as well as a [request to improve the output within Scratchpad](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=836849).

Comment: I tried that scratchpad and it's ridiculously broken. When you click inspect, toolbar appears that cannot be hidden and the other button puts `/** undefined **/` in the code. Are they serious about this?

Comment: Yes, the UI is not very user friendly. I've filed a [bug report for adding a toggle button for the side panel](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1337083) right now. The `/** undefined **/` output is only shown when the executed script doesn't have a return value.