# Firebug is not working on Mozilla version 52

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

Today i have installed a new version(52) of firefox in machine and add the extension firebug .but it not showing in toolbar. i have restarted several times still no luck and then again i have installed ,intstallation gets success,not showing in toolbar.

Again I have customize and enable the firebug but when I clicked it's not responding and showing the firebug inspect tool.

On 17-3-2017 uninstalled and installed the 52 version of firefox and add firebug but it not showing there?

see the screenshot below.

[image]

The problem is happen only in the version.Anybody have idea.
[image]

Comment: I tested installing Firebug in a fresh profile using FF 52.0. The icon showed up in the toolbar just fine. Something else is going on. Did you check to see if the icon was available under customize Firefox (icon on hte far right of that toolbar, then click "+ Customize" at the bottom of the popup)? It should show automatically in the toolbar, but it might be in the customization area.

Comment: @makyen I have enable the firebug icon under toolbar but if you hover or right click the icon it is in deactivated state..Some compatability issue is thr

Comment: In my testing on a fresh profile, the button was functional, not a disabled button (i.e. it was clickable). Clicking the firebug button opened the DevTools. You can use the actual Firebug if you disable e10s for that profile. A popup gives you the option to do this the first time you click on the Firebug icon. So, something else is going on. We need more information. Please [edit] the question to provide more information so we can duplicate the problem. Try creating a new profile and freshly install Firebug.

Comment: Please take a screen-GIF of the problem. One program that will let you do so is [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) on Windows and Mac). As I've said, I have tried to reproduce this (on FF52.0, both with and without e10s (multiprocessing) enabled), but been unable to do so. Please provide more information, e.g. operating system, config, did you use a fresh profile? We need to be able to duplicate the problem. Try a clean install of Firefox with a new profile.

Comment: @Makyen kindly see the screencast of issue here http://recordit.co/cCYdvh2S1S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebug is not working with Firefox version 50.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800173/firebug-is-not-working-with-firefox-version-50-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why got Firebug removed after updating Firefox to version 50?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744448/why-got-firebug-removed-after-updating-firefox-to-version-50)

Answer (score 4):

Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://getfirebug.com/). New installations of Firefox have [multi-process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) enabled. With that the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) are opened instead of Firebug when you click the Firebug button and a notification is shown giving a short explanation:

[image: Notification explaining the merge of Firebug with the Firefox DevTools]

You can [get Firebug back by deactivating the multi-process feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744448/why-got-firebug-removed-after-updating-firefox-to-version-50/40748127#40748127), though this is only a short-term solution, as multi-process will be mandatory at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Firebug is (sadly) no longer updated, or supporting latest Firefox versions.

Comment: Do you have any idea upto which version firebug supported.

Comment: The last version of Firebug claimed:
Firebug 2.0.19 is compatible with Firefox 30 – 54 but the fact remains, that it's wonderful story has ended, and I guess a lot of us finally have to jump ship to Chrome or of course Firefox's built in dev tools

Comment: @ mayersdesign  thanks ,I have already shipped to chrome  due to firebug is very slow process after 39 version of firefox and the browser get hangs out alternatively.i need to check an issue with firefox browser at that time unfortunately installed firefox 52, got this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you like Firebug and Firefox, then you can use:

- Waterfox 55 (based in FF56)+ Firebug 2.0.19 (install extension and restart)
- Palemoon 27.6 (based in FF pre Australis and FF52 upgrades) +firebug 1.12.8.1
- An oudated and non supported Firefox

Waterfox and Palemoon are active projects, and they will continue supporting classic Firefox extensions/addons