# Firebug shows no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I have the latest version of Firefox (50.0.2) and Firebug (2.0.18). I wanted to debug my JavaScript code but Firebug tells me: No JavaScript on this page. 
I cleared my activity list as it has been told in this thread: [Firebug says "No Javascript on this page", even though JavaScript does exist on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086478/firebug-says-no-javascript-on-this-page-even-though-javascript-does-exist-on)

But nothing changed. As Firebug's FAQ told there might be some error in the JavaScript sources, I tried on other pages. But even on pages as google or facebook, I still receive the same message. 
What can I do to make Firebug work again?

Best regards
Marco

Comment: [The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer. We invite you to use the Firefox built-in DevTools instead.](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebug says "No Javascript on this page", even though JavaScript does exist on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086478/firebug-says-no-javascript-on-this-page-even-though-javascript-does-exist-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only your problem. New Firefox don't want to cooperate with Firebug as he did yet couple days ago.